# What indexes to create in a snapshot history table SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, snapshot

I have a snapshot table with snapshots to be taken on a monthly basis.

Which indexes would be better for such a huge table?

The filter will be on snapshot_date but most of the fields will be queried upon?

Thanks!

Comment: posting a minimal structure of your table may help to answer.

Comment: Also post sample queries. You mentioned snapshot_date filter - are there any others in WHERE/JOIN clauses?